# Composer failing to bring in correct references from local repository

Tags: composer-php

I added an autoload.psr-4 reference in a repository referenced by a symlink. Composer is failing to pick up the new reference even though I am doing `composer dump-autoload`. For good measure, I found a stale reference to a framework library that now lives in a separate directory. Even after `rm -rf vendor` and `composer install`, the stale reference is in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` and the new reference is not.

`vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`  in the core repository has the new reference and not the stale reference.

**core/composer.json** Definition for `Us\OurLibrary\NewReference`

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Us\\OurLibrary\\NewReference\\": "NewReference/",
```

**core/composer/autoload_psr4.php** Reference to NewReference.

```
return array(
    'Us\\OurLibrary\\NewReference\\' => array($baseDir . '/NewReference'),
```

**framework/composer.json**

```
  "repositories": [{
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../OurLibrary/core",
      "options": { "symlink": true } }],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Us\\OurLibrary\\Framework\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

**project/composer.json**

```
  "repositories": [{
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../OurLibrary/core",
      "options": { "symlink": true }
    }, {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../OurLibrary/framework",
      "options": { "symlink": true }
    }],
```

**project/composer/autoload_psr4.php** There is no entry for NewReference, and the entry for Framework incorrectly points to the folder that was removed from `core`.

```
return array(
    'Us\\OurLibrary\\Framework\\' => array($vendorDir . '/us/core/Framework', $vendorDir . '/us/framework/src'),
    //
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `composer.lock` and run `composer install` again.